# Передача сигнала между окнами

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Имеется **`2`** окна, код для каждой создан в отдельных файлах.

В первом окне **`Window`** есть кнопка `self.button`

Во втором окне **`SecondWindow`** есть `self.label_1`, текст которой должен поменяться (методом `def func(self)`), про нажатии кнопки `self.button` из первого окна **`Window`**.

Сейчас я не понимаю, как во втором файле **SecondWindow.py** для `self.button.clicked.connect` назначить правильно метод. 
Меня запутал класс `MyBar(QWidget)` из-за **parent** в `def __init__(self, parent):`

Код в первом файле **Window.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 10, 0)
        self.title = QLabel()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('КНОПКА')
        self.button.setFixedSize(160, 25)

        self.title.setFixedHeight(32)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(MyBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end - self.start
            self.parent.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                    self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                    self.parent.width(),
                                    self.parent.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey;")
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.page_1)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.myBar = MyBar(self)  # +++

        self.layout.addWidget(self.myBar)  # +++

        self.layout.addWidget(self.Content, 1)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.setMinimumSize(400, 200)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)  # +++
        self.show()
```

Код во втором файле **SecondWindow.py**:

````
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFileDialog, QComboBox
from Window import MainWindow


class Ui_Form0(object):
    def setupUi0(self, Form0):
        Form0.setObjectName("Form0")
        Form0.setEnabled(True)
        Form0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 500, 300))
        Form0.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form0.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        Form0.setStatusTip("")
        Form0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.retranslateUi(Form0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form0)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form0", "Главное меню"))


class MenuWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('нажми на кнопку')
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.firstMainWindow = MainWindow()

    def func(self):
        self.label_1.setText('КНОПКА нажата')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui0 = MenuWindow()
    ui0.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**q1299235_Window.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1299235_SecondWindow import MenuWindow                                # +++


class MyBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 10, 0)
        self.title = QLabel()
        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('КНОПКА')
        self.button.setFixedSize(160, 25)

        self.title.setFixedHeight(32)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(MyBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end - self.start
            self.parent.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                    self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                    self.parent.width(),
                                    self.parent.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey;")
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.page_1)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.myBar = MyBar(self)       
        self.layout.addWidget(self.myBar)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.Content, 1)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.setMinimumSize(400, 200)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)  
#        self.show()

        self.menuWindow = MenuWindow()                                        # +++
        self.myBar.button.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow.func)               # +++
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1299235_SecondWindow.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from Window import MainWindow


class Ui_Form0(object):
    def setupUi0(self, Form0):
        Form0.setObjectName("Form0")
        Form0.setEnabled(True)
        Form0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 500, 300))
        Form0.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form0.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        Form0.setStatusTip("")
        Form0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.retranslateUi(Form0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form0)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form0", "Главное меню"))


class MenuWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('нажми на кнопку')
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        
#        self.firstMainWindow = MainWindow()

    def func(self):
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 500, 300))
        self.label_1.setText('КНОПКА нажата')
        self.show()                                                         # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui0 = MenuWindow()
    ui0.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ник, есть ли какой-то способ, который позволит оставить в **SecondWindow**  ```from Window import MainWindow```? Мне необходимо передавать данные из   **SecondWindow** в **Window**, дополнительные данные, которые я не стал указывать в коде, чтобы не усложнять код

Comment: @dutik вы спросили: '...self.label_1, текст которой должен поменяться (методом def func(self)), про нажатии кнопки self.button...' -  я вам ответил. Примите решение о правильности моего ответа. Дополнительно вам  скажу, что выход всегда есть и вам ненужно этого делать чтобы передать данные. `У вас проблема XY`.

Comment: Я просил другое,  как сделать,  что в секонд виндовс заработал клик конект

Comment: Ник, вы говорите, что для передачи данных из **SecondWindow** мне не понадобится ```from Window import MainWindow```. Как этого добиться? И как получать сигнал для ```self.button.clicked.connect```?

Comment: @dutik задайте новый вопрос, в котором приведите полный текст ваших модулей (ничего не скрывая) и по шагам опишите что вы хотите сделать. Например так: 1. запускаем что (укажите имя модуля. которое надо запустить). 2. нажимает на что или не нажимаем (укажите действия которые надо сделать). 3. хочу чтобы произошло (опишите что вы хотите чтобы произошло ). 4. и т.д.

Comment: @dutik не надо писать: 'как передать сигнал между окнами' или 'что вас запутал parent... ', напишите что вы хотите получить в результате выполнения каких-то действий.

Comment: Если в каждом файле по 1000 строк? Попытаться упростить код?

Comment: @dutik пример должен быть минимальный в том плане, что он содержит только то что влияет на проблему.  Пример должен быть воспроизводимый - т.е. он копируется, запускается и демонстрирует суть проблемы. The END.